# Is there a way to make 'for' loop for function?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a lot of functions , with just a little changes in them ?
Something like :

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
   def i():
      if i=='a':
         print 'a'
```

I know code looks a little bit wild , but it how I see it in my head, is there any way to achieve it? Without making 3 separate functions ? Thank you

Comment: Related, possibly dupe: [Creating functions in a loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/3431676)

Comment: The code you have shown works perfectly fine (though it has some problems explained in the dupe). What are you trying to do in specific?

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically create function objects at all?

Comment: Indeed, why create several similar functions instead of one function that takes more arguments and exhibits more dynamic behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(i):
    if i=='a':
        print 'a'

for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    func(i)
```

Is this what you are looking for?